# How does IIS work with Angular to serve content?

Tags: angular, iis, kestrel-http-server

I just read some instructions on how to host an ASP.NET Angular app in IIS, but the details of how IIS communicates with Angular's server remains a mystery.

How does IIS or IIS Express know the existence of Angular's http server and how does it communicate with it? ASP.NET's built-in Kestrel requires an IIS module run under IIS, but Angular doesn't have such as requirement. Moreover, since Angular can coexist with ASP.NET Core, the interaction among Kestrel, Angular and IIS becomes even more of a mystery.

Comment: When you're using Angular Universal, Angular's built-in server that you get with `ng serve` isn't part of the equation. Express or IIS merely pre-renders the Angular application and serves the files. From there, Angular takes over on the client side.

Comment: That Express (or the .NET equivalent) application gives you server-side hooks that you can use as well. Angular Universal is basically a mono-repo for client and server side code. You can share functions, interfaces, types, etc. It's a powerful combination, imo.

Comment: Any routes in the Express application would be service endpoints to your Angular app, available on the same domain and port.

Comment: Prerender as in premasticating the files? You mean it draws up the stuff it knows about than hands it off to Angular for the rest?

Comment: It will render whatever component(s) you specify in your angular.json. It will literally take that component, make service calls, get data, bind it and render out all of the HTML, then serve it complete. Otherwise, all of the JS files have to be downloaded first, then rendered by Angular client-side.

Comment: Ok.  But how is it possible for IIS to do this without some kind of special handler or module?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the IIS side, but on the Node side there is an `ngExpressEngine` that boostraps the `AppServerModule`